# How to check if checkbox in gridview is checked

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, grid, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridview, and in one of the columns is a checkbox.  I want to check to see if the checkbox in that column is selected in the focused row, and if so, perform some action.  How should I go about checking if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Please post the code for this.

Comment: Do you use data-bindings? Adding some code would help us. I don't know the technologies, where DevExpress grids are available for. WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET? WinForms?

Answer (score 2):

```
   bool value = (bool) gridView.GetRowCellValue(gridView.FocusedRowHandle, column);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataBinding it is very easy. For example:

```
public class MyClass(){
   public MyClass(){

   }

   public bool IsTrue
   {
     get{;}
     set{;}
   }
}

List<MyClass> manyMyClassObjects = new List<MyClass>();
//Add some values for sure

GridControl.DataSource = manyMyClassObjects;
```

Now the IsTrue property is binded to the Grid. The GridView just present the underlaying Data. If you change a value in the Grid it changes the value of your DataSource Object. This will work with any Property which implements a setter for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[gvExcelSheet.RowCount];
                for (int j = 0; j < gvExcelSheet.RowCount; j++)
                {
                    rows[j] = gvExcelSheet.GetDataRow(j);
                    if ((bool)rows[j]["yourcheckboxcolumnname"] == true)
                    {
                        //your code
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as below:

```
bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(gvMain.SelectedRowsCount);
```